# Search and Replace Text in CSV file using Python

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I just started with Python 3.4.2 and trying to find and replace text in csv file.

In Details, `Input.csv` file contain below line:

```
0,0,0,13,.\New_Path-1.1.12\Impl\Appli\Library\Module_RM\Code\src\Exception.cpp

0,0,0,98,.\Old_Path-1.1.12\Impl\Appli\Library\Prof_bus\Code\src\Wrapper.cpp

0,0,0,26,.\New_Path-1.1.12\Impl\Support\Custom\Vital\Code\src\Interface.cpp

0,0,0,114,.\Old_Path-1.1.12\Impl\Support\Custom\Cust\Code\src\Config.cpp
```

I maintained my strings to be searched in other file named `list.csv`

```
Module_RM
Prof_bus
Vital
Cust
```

Now I need to go through each line of `Input.csv`and replace the last column with the matched string.

So my end result should be like this:

```
0,0,0,13,Module_RM  
0,0,0,98,Prof_bus  
0,0,0,26,Vital  
0,0,0,114,Cust
```

I read the input files first line as a list. So text which i need to replace came in `line[4]`. I am reading each module name in the `list.csv` file and checking if there is any match of text in `line[4]`. I am not able to make that `if` condition `true`.  Please let me know if it is not a proper search.

```
import csv
import re  

with open("D:\\My_Python\\New_Python_Test\\Input.csv") as source, open("D:\\My_Python\\New_Python_Test\\List.csv") as module_names, open("D:\\My_Python\\New_Python_Test\\Final_File.csv","w",newline="") as result:
reader=csv.reader(source)
module=csv.reader(module_names)
writer=csv.writer(result)
#lines=source.readlines()
for line in reader:
for mod in module_names:
    if any([mod in s for s in line]):
        line.replace(reader[4],mod)
        print ("YES")
    writer.writerow("OUT")
    print (mod)
module_names.seek(0)
lines=reader
```

Please guide me to complete this task.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: try `if any([mod in s for s in line.split(',')]):`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, actually while reading module list, there is a space at the end of the module name. By using strip(), the extra spacing is removed and now i am able to find sub string in the string. Now moving forward to complete my task. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

At-last i succeeded in solving this problem!

The below code works well!

```
import csv

with open("D:\\My_Python\\New_Python_Test\\Input.csv") as source, open("D:\\My_Python\\New_Python_Test\\List.csv") as module_names, open("D:\\My_Python\\New_Python_Test\\Final_File.csv","w",newline="") as result:
    reader=csv.reader(source)
    module=csv.reader(module_names)
    writer=csv.writer(result)
    flag=False
    for row in reader:
        i=row[4]
        for s in module_names:
            k=s.strip()
            if i.find(k)!=-1 and flag==False:
                row[4]=k
                writer.writerow(row)
                flag=True
        module_names.seek(0)
        flag=False
```

Thanks for people who tried to solve! If you have any better coding practices please do share!

Good Luck!